# Contributions not showing up under Github profile?

Tags: git, github

I've been working on a project by myself, which I've been consistently committing and pushing to my repository. 
[image]

In the project, I can see all my commits, however, looking over at my profile doesn't show a trace of activity.

[image]

Is there a reason unbeknownst to me why this is occurring?

Comment: Can you share links to your profile and the project on github?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to see whether its a public or private repository. If its a private one, you can activate a flag inside [settings](https://github.com/settings/profile):

> Include private contributions on my profile Get credit for all your
>   work by showing the number of contributions to private repositories on
>   your profile without any repository or organization information. Learn
>   how we count contributions.

Further you have to register the email address you are using for doing this commit, most likely this is the one you stored inside your ~/.gitconfig

```
[user]
    email = myemail
```

This can be also done via [settings](https://github.com/settings/emails)

Furthermore github is providng a FAQ-article for this question [here](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile/).

Comment: my local name and email were previously blank, so I set them to what my global name and email are. Tried committing & pushing once again to see if it would behave differently, but it still doesn't show up under activity.

Comment: Have you merged your branch (commits) with default branch (e.g. master)?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the repo was created by https://github.com/DavidRodden but your commits are all associated to https://github.com/David-Rodden, which can be seen by going to the commit tab in your project.

Comment: So if I commit with David-Rodden even though I've created the repo through DavidRodden, will it just not show up under contributions?

Comment: It depends on which user.email you commit.